# Jquery effect on form select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have a script thats validating some form information. Currently it adds a CSS class of .error (adds red border) and also applies the shake effect when the input value is seen to be less than 1 character.

I also need to do this on various selects in the form if nothing has been selected. What would I need to do with the following code to get this to work please?

```
//check if inputs aren't empty
   var fields = $('.validate');
   var error = 0;
   fields.each(function(){
       var value = $(this).val();
       if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] ) {
           $(this).addClass('error');
           $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

           error++;
       } else {
           $(this).addClass('valid');
       }
   });
```

I have limited Javascript / Jquery knowledge and this is a modified script I found online. You can see it in action here: [site](https://www.geniusmoney.co.uk/users/register2.php), step 2 of the form is where you can find the selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if a selection was made by checking if there is an option selected :

```
if ($("#mySelect option:selected").length){

//something has been selected   
}

if (!$("#mySelect option:selected").length){

//nothing has been selected   
}
```

Comment: So what would I do for something not selected?

Comment: simply reverse the conditional statement by using the "!" operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jQuery validation plugin instead it will make ur life way easier specially with errors and error displaying..

http://jqueryvalidation.org/